# Syntax to instantiate chart.js chart

Tags: chart.js

Using chart.js 2.0.0-beta2.
Using this syntax to instantiate a bar chart, taken from the documentation, works great:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData);
```

Am trying instead the following since I want eventually to use logarithmic axes (and a lot of other options), which seems to require this style:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d'); 
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'Bar', 
    data: barChartData      
});
```

That doesn't seem to work, no chart drawn, no JS error in the console.

Thanks for any help. Also thanks to the people working on chart.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in barChartData?

It should look something like this (from the documentation):

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        },
        // Additional data sets go here.
    ],
};
```

http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/#bar-chart-example-usage

Edit -

Change

```
type: 'Bar',
```

to

```
type: 'bar',
```

Edit #2 -

You can confirm your using the correct version of Chart.JS by pulling 2.0 beta 2 from here:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0-beta2/Chart.min.js

Comment: Content of barChartData variable is not the problem (I'm using the same syntax you reference from the documentation) - as I noted I am getting proper charts as expected with the first myBarChart = new Chart... syntax.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that and tried it already, Doesn't work. Can you replicate the problem, trying the two different styles of syntax? Use 'Bar' for both, 'bar' doesn't work for either. Thanks for your response btw.

Comment: Go to jsfiddle and make an example there, then post the link to it.

Comment: @norrhult I made a jsfiddle -- and it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/r4qj8et0/1/

Comment: Thanks. Still not working, even copied your code from your jsfiddle to test that. With syntax you use there it doesn't work for me, I change to var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData); - it works. Can't understand it. Tried different browsers, turning off various js libraries. Everything I can think of.

Comment: If that's the case -- then you're not using 2.0 I imagine.

Comment: Downloaded Mar 23, Readme says 2.0. But yes that's the most logical explanation. Downloaded again. Doesn't help.

Comment: Take a look at the external resources in the fiddle that I linked above. Reference both of those instead of what you're referencing.

Comment: OK spoke too soon. Downloaded again and now it's working. How does this work, do I accept your original response? Answer was strictly speaking in your comments here.